# How to convert list of hashmaps into one hasmap in clojure?

Tags: list, clojure, hashmap

I have a list which looks like this:

```
({:course 2, :mark 9} {:course 5, :mark 8} {:course 6, :mark 10})
```

And i want to convert it to hashmap:

```
{:2 9 :5 8 :6 10}
```

List was created from mysql database, i dont know can i get that datas from database in some other format, which will be easier to convert to one hashmap, i used java.jdbc query function.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(fn [data] (into {} (map (juxt :course :mark) data)))
```

on

```
(list {:course 2, :mark 9} {:course 5, :mark 8} {:course 6, :mark 10})
```

produces

```
{2 9, 5 8, 6 10}
```

The `keyword` function does not accept numbers as arguments, so I don't think you can get quite what you were looking for. But digits are as good keys as keywords anyway.

---

Wrong! As others have demonstrated, Clojure accepts digit *strings* as keywords. We can adapt the above to use such:

```
(fn [data] (into {} (map (juxt (comp keyword str :course) :mark) data)))
```

on

```
(list {:course 2, :mark 9} {:course 5, :mark 8} {:course 6, :mark 10})
```

produces

```
{:2 9, :5 8, :6 10}
```

But, as I've said, I think this is needlessly risky. Why not just use the numbers as keys?

---

Further to using digit (strings) as keywords:

The [reader doc about symbols](http://clojure.org/reader#The%20Reader--Reader%20forms) says

- *Symbols begin with a non-numeric character ...*
- *Keywords are like symbols, except: ... (further restricted)*

Comment: `juxt` is a great idea here! For the sake of the exercice, here's the solution to get the exact requested output: 
`(fn [data] (into {} (map (juxt #(keyword (str (:course %))) :mark) data)))`

Comment: @leontalbot I've done it slightly differently, Leon. I'm still surprised that digit-string keywords are accepted. Whatever, the `juxt` with the keywords-as-functions is pretty expressive. Another take on your way to express the inner function is `#(-> % :course str keyword)`, if you're playing code golf: still a character longer than mine, heh heh.

Answer (score 1):

Another variant.  (Probably less efficient than Thumbnail's if you've got a lot of data.)

```
(zipmap (map (comp keyword str :course)  data)
        (map :mark data))
```

where `data` is in the format specified in the question.

Comment: ... or `(apply zipmap (map #(map % data) [(comp keyword str :course) :mark]))`